# Styling php email to allow Microsoft Outlook to read style

Tags: php, css, email, outlook, phpmailer

I am running into an issue where Microsoft Office doesn't read any inline style or classes I create. At first, I just had inline styles setup, but read that Outlook doesn't read this type of code. I then tried the class method, but still am not having any luck. I am using PHPMailer to send the emails.

Does any one see anything in my code that would be preventing this from working?

The parts I specifically changed are '.emailHeader' and '.Logo'. The rest are still in inline style formation.

```
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to 

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = '
        <head>
        <style>
        .logo {
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
        }
        .emailHeader {
            max-width: 600px;
            height: auto;
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            padding: 20px 0;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header-background" style="background:#16597B;width:100%;max-width:100%;height:auto;">
                <div class="emailHeader">
                    <div class="logo"><a href=""><img src="Logo.png" style="width:200px;height:auto;text-align:center"></a></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                    <div id="email-to" style="color:#FFF;font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size: 2.5em;margin-top:35px;">Hi Team,</div>
                        <div id="email-header-description" style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.4em;color:#d0dde4;margin-top:45px;">
                            You have received a new inquiry<br><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="email-link" style="width:100%;padding:15px;height:auto;background:#EBEBEB;position:relative;">
                    <div id="email-link-container" style="width:600px;height:auto;margin:auto;text-align:left;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width:600px; font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em;">
                        <p>Name: ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '</p>
                        <p>Email: ' . $client_email . '</p>
                        <p>Phone: ' . $client_phone . '</p>
                        <p>Company: ' . $company . '</p>
                        <p>Contact Details: ' . $details . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    ';
```

Comment: It's really hard; Outlook totally sucks for styling HTML; it's packed with glitches and idiosyncracies.

Comment: @Synchro That's what I have read. The email I am creating is going to be very simple. For instance the code I showed above, I am just trying to get the logo to be the right size. Currently, it is formatting as `width: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

try to delete last `</div>`. When I tried the code its gave me error there

Comment: Thanks for the catch. This didn't help with the style unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the <html> surrounding tags, as well as other common head tags like meta charset. All of that is valid to use in PHPMailer->Body.

For a recent project, I took a close look at one of the Cerberus templates, and ended up copying & pasting the basic outline and filling in my own content. Check out the Cerberus template below:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/master/cerberus-fluid.html